# Javascript - Time between two dates

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a function that calculates time difference between two timestamps like for example.

```
Ex1: 23-04-2014 08:00:00
Ex2: 24-04-2014 12:56:40
```

I partly succeeded after some research but I don't know how to calc the days within the hours.

So the function should count more than 24 hours if you understand what I mean, I don't want x days.

Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function calculateTime() {
             var valuestart = "08:48:30";
             var valuestop = "17:56:37";

             var hourStart = new Date("01/01/2014 " + valuestart).getHours();
             var hourEnd = new Date("01/01/20014 " + valuestop).getHours();
             var hourDiff = hourEnd - hourStart;  

             var minStart = new Date("01/01/20014 " + valuestart).getMinutes();
             var minEnd = new Date("01/01/20014 " + valuestop).getMinutes();
             var minDiff = minEnd - minStart;

             var secStart = new Date("01/01/20014 " + valuestart).getSeconds();
             var secEnd = new Date("01/01/20014 " + valuestop).getSeconds();
             var secDiff = secEnd - secStart;

        if (hourDiff < 10) hourDiff = "0" + hourDiff;
        if (minDiff < 10) minDiff = "0" + minDiff;
        if (secDiff < 10) secDiff = "0" + secDiff;

        $("p").html("<b>Time difference:</b> " + hourDiff + ":" + minDiff + ":" + secDiff)             

    }
    calculateTime();
    });
```

Here is my fiddle: [`http://jsfiddle.net/Ma4sb/`](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma4sb/)

Comment: You can subtract two `Date` objects from each other and get the result in number of milliseconds. Then just convert to hours.

Comment: SO doesn't like answers that point to libraries, but you should really check out moment.js.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I don't mind such answers, as long as they do not ignore the presented question/code (i.e. an explanation of why the current code doesn't work, and how it could be fixed is a requirement for an answer). That is, I hold the reverse view: "SO doesn't like *questions* that ask for libraries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, (and assuming your end date was a typo):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function calculateTime() {
         var valuestart = "08:48:30";
         var valuestop = "17:56:37";

         var dateStart = new Date("01/01/2014 " + valuestart);
         var dateEnd = new Date("01/01/2014 " + valuestop);
         var secDiff = (dateEnd - dateStart)/1000;   // in seconds.

         var hourDiff = Math.floor(secDiff / (60 * 60));

         secDiff -= hourDiff * 60 * 60;

         var minDiff = Math.floor(secDiff / 60);
         secDiff -= minDiff * 60;


         if (hourDiff < 10) hourDiff = "0" + hourDiff;
         if (minDiff < 10) minDiff = "0" + minDiff;
         if (secDiff < 10) secDiff = "0" + secDiff;

         $("p").html("<b>Time difference:</b> " + hourDiff + ":" + minDiff + ":" + secDiff)             

    }
    calculateTime();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ma4sb/2/

So, for example, if we move the `dateEnd` to `01/02/2014`, you'll see:

```
Time difference: 33:08:07
```

Which *I think* is what you wanted. If not, you can easily convert to days by dividing the hours by 24.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!